# Power Analysis and the non central t distribution: what is the non-centrality parameter?

Tags: t-test, statistical-power, non-central

I want to investigate the power of t test in detecting shift so I have a sample $X_1, \dots,X_n \sim N(\mu_x,\sigma)$ and other sample $Y_1, \dots,Y_n \sim N(\mu_y,\sigma)$.

My null hypothesis is $H_0:\mu_Y-\mu_Y=0$ the alternative is $H_1:\mu_Y-\mu_Y=\delta$. Now I want to simulate these samples. I know it's a non-central t-distribution but I do not know how the non-centrality parameter relates to the difference in the means.

What's the distribution of the t-statistic for a two-sample test under the alternative hypothesis where the two samples are from Normal distributions differing only in their means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is a geometric view of the t-test (a similar view is also expressed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/365070)).

The t-statistic, which is a ratio of the sample mean and the sample standard deviation, follows a ratio distribution, which is when properly scaled the t-distribution.

$$T \sim \frac{Z+\mu}{\sqrt{V_\nu/\nu}} \sim \text{t-distribution with $\nu$ degrees of freedom} $$

where $Z \sim N(0,1)$ is standard normal distributed, $V_\nu \sim \chi^2_\nu$ is $\chi^2$-distributed with $\nu$ degrees of freedom, and $\mu$ is a non-centrality parameter.

[image: example]

In the image above we plotted simulations sample $X$ and $Y$ with sample size $n=5$.

- On the x-axis is the **difference in the sample means**. The distribution is $$\bar{y}-\bar{x} \sim N(\mu_Y-\mu_X, \frac{2}{n} \sigma^2)$$
- On the y-axis is the **pooled variance**. The distribution is $$\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar{x})^2+\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-\bar{y})^2} \sim \sigma \chi_{2n-2}$$ where $\sigma \chi_{2n-2}$ is a scaled $\chi_{2n-2}$ distribution.

Both the 'difference in the sample means' and the 'pooled variance' relate to the unknown deviation parameter $\sigma$ which is a nuisance parameter. But, their ratio does not depend on $\sigma$, and that is how we can perform a t-test. The ratio, the t-statistic (note we apply scaling to the numerator and denominator), follows a t-distribution.

$$\begin{array}{rcl}T &= & \frac{1/(\sqrt{2/n})}{1/\sqrt{2n-2}} \frac{\bar{y}-\bar{x}}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar{x})^2+\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-\bar{y})^2}}\\
& \sim& \frac{Z}{\sqrt{V_\nu/\nu}} \\&\sim &\text{t-distribution with $\nu$ degrees of freedom} \hphantom{\text{and noncentrality parameter $\frac{\sqrt{2n-2}}{\sqrt{2/n}}$ }} \end{array}$$

In the lower image we showed how the distribution will look like when the difference $\mu_y-\mu_x \neq 0$ and would be shifted by 2 standard deviations. Then the distribution of the t-statistic would become

$$\begin{array}{rcl}T &= & \frac{1/(\sqrt{2/n})}{1/\sqrt{2n-2}} \frac{\bar{y}-\bar{x}+ c\sigma}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar{x})^2+\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-\bar{y})^2}}\\
& \sim& \frac{Z+c \frac{1}{\sqrt{2/n}} }{\sqrt{V_\nu/\nu}} \\&\sim &\text{t-distribution with $\nu$ degrees of freedom and noncentrality parameter $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2/n}}$ } \end{array}$$

So the power for a 95% confidence interval can be expressed **in terms of the shift in standard deviations**:

[image: power]

You do not know the standard deviation, so you can not express the power in terms of the effect size in absolute terms, but you *can* express the power in terms of the relative effect size (relative to the standard deviation).

---

You can generalize this result for different sample sizes, but not for different populations variances (which is the [Behrens Fisher problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behrens%E2%80%93Fisher_problem))