# The probability of making a Type S error, and the average amount of magnification (type M error) as a function of power

Tags: hypothesis-testing, type-i-and-ii-errors, research-design, reproducibility

When you filter on only viewing results with p<alpha, some of those "statistically significant" results go in the wrong direction. This is called a Type S error ("S" for sign). And the average effect size in those selected results is larger than the true effect size. Believing the magnitude of these effect sizes has been called a Type M error. More details in the reference below.

Type S errors are more common, and effect magnification is larger, when the power of a study is low.

My question is: What are the equations that compute the probability of type S error and the average magnification factor from power?

1. Gelman, A. & Carlin, J. [Beyond Power Calculations Assessing Type S (Sign) and Type M (Magnitude) Errors.](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Egelman/research/published/retropower_final.pdf) Perspectives on Psychological Science 9, 641–651 (2014). DOI: 10.1177/1745691614551642

Comment: +1. Doesn't this become clear when contemplating a standard two-sided t-test, where the risk is evenly divided into the left and right tails?  That's probably the paradigmatic situation the writers have in mind.  The "average magnification error from power" is not a frequentist concept, btw, because it assumes some distribution of alternative hypotheses.  It would be more appropriate to plot a "magnification curve," akin to a power curve.

Comment: @whuber  S-error is more nuanced than that. If the null hypothesis is true, half of false positives will be in one direction and half in the other (assuming two-sided P-values). But s-errors assume the null is not true. Most p<0.05 are in the correct direction, but some are in the wrong direction, a type-S error. How frequently this happens depends on alpha and power. I've only seen functions of  Effect/S and sample size. It seems that it ought to be a simple function of computed power (for a specified alternative hypothesis, alpha, and sample sizes) but I can't find that equation.

Comment: @whuber Type M errors are poorly named because it is not really an error. But if you only look at results with p<0.05, on average the effect size will be larger than the true effect size. The observed (and selected) effect size is magnified. Or (sort of) you've made an error of Magnitude. The p-value filter magnifies effect sizes.

Comment: Yes, those phenomena are clear.  For certain simple tests we might expect these error rates to depend on the power, but in general (where the alternate hypothesis is composite) I think it could be more complicated than that.

Comment: Related and perhaps of interest: Andrew Gelman + collaborators investigate type M error (aka exaggeration ratio) as a function of signal-to-noise (SNR, ie. effect size) ratio and power in a series of three "shrinkage" papers: https://doi.org/10.1080/00031305.2021.1938225 (Fig. 1), https://doi.org/10.1002/sim.9173 (Fig. 3) and https://doi.org/10.1111/stan.12241.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Sketch of the t-test

Let $x_1, \dots, x_n \sim N(\mu_1,\sigma^2)$ and $y_1, \dots, y_n \sim N(\mu_2,\sigma^2)$ be independent samples. Let's define

- The raw effect

  $\theta = \mu_2-\mu_1$
- The estimate of the raw effect

  $\hat{\theta} = \bar{Y} - \bar{X} \sim N \left(\theta,\frac{2}{n} \sigma^2 \right)$
- The standard error of the raw effect
  $\text{se}(\hat\theta) = \sqrt\frac{2}{n} \hat\sigma = \sqrt\frac{2}{n}  \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar{X})^2 + \sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\bar{Y})^2}{2n -2}} \sim \sigma\sqrt{\frac{2}{n}} \sqrt{\frac{1}{2n-2}} \chi_{2n-2}$

where $a\chi_{2n-2}$ means a scaled chi distribution (also known as a case of the gamma distribution).

And the t-statistic is defined as

$$t = \frac{\hat\theta}{\text{se}(\hat\theta)} \sim t_{2n-2,\theta\sqrt{n/2}}$$

this statistic follows a [non-central t-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_t-distribution) where $2n-2$ are the degrees of freedom and $\theta \sqrt{n/2}$ is the non-centrality parameter.

A typical hypothesis test will regard the significance based on whether or not the t-statistic is above some level. (and the reason for all this hassle with the t-statistic is that it is a [pivotal statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivotal_quantity) that does not depend on the standard deviation $\sigma$ of the population.)

#### Geometric view of the t-test

A geometric view of the t-test can be made with a scatterplot with $\hat{\theta}$ on the horizontal axis and $\text{se}(\hat{\theta})$ on the vertical axis.

We do this below in an example with simulations for the null hypothesis $\theta = 0$ and for the alternative hypothesis $d = \frac{\theta}{\sigma} = 0.5$ and $d=2$ (where the [effect size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size) $d$ is expressed *relative* to the population deviation, see also the question [Power Analysis and the non central t distribution: what is the non-centrality parameter?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/491720/)). The simulations are made with samples of size $n=5$.

(click on the image to view a larger size)
[image: example of t-test]

<sup>*Figure 1: Simulations of results for an independent two sample t-test with sample sizes 5. We simulated 3000 points under the null hypothesis of zero effect size (left) and under the alternative hypotheses of an effect size equal to $d = 0.5$ (middle) and $d=2$ (right). The effect size is used for the horizontal axis and the standard error for the vertical axis. The t-statistic is proportional to the ratio of the two axes $t = \frac{\hat{\theta}}{\text{se}(\hat{\theta})}$. The angle relates to the t-statistic and points at a smaller angle will have a larger t-statistic. Points with $|t|>2.3$ are considered significantly different, and in the case of the null hypothesis this occurs approximately 5% of the time.*</sup>

#### Graphical illustration of the functions

Let's focus on the middle case of the three simulations, the t-tests when the true effect size is $d=0.5$. We can plot the distribution of the effect size for the cases when the observation is significant and for the cases when the observation is not significant:

[image: distribution of significant and non-significant cases]
<sup>*Figure 2: Histogram of the 3000 cases in the middle plot from Figure 1, when the true effect size is $d=0.5$. Based on these histograms one can compute power, s-type error and m-type error.*</sup>

The consequence of the hypothesis test is that mostly relatively large effects are accepted/reported (smaller effects than the true effect size can be reported, if the estimated standard deviation is small). This makes that reported values have a bias and are often larger than the true effect sizes.

- **The rejection region** is based on the distribution of the null hypothesis and for a two sided test it is such that $\alpha/2$ percent of the results on both sides of the distribution are falsely rejected if the null hypothesis is true. In the first panel of Figure 1, the simulations when the null hypothesis is true, we reject the null hypothesis when $|t|>2.3$, this occurs in 5% of the cases.
- **The power** is the probability to reject when the alternative hypothesis is correct. In the Figure 1 we see that this occurs in respectively 10% and 80% of the cases for relative effect sizes $d=0.5$ and $d=2$.
- **The S-type error** is the fraction of the rejected/significant cases with the wrong sign (this occurs mostly when the power is small). In the Figure 2 this is the fraction of the red area compared to the total of the red and green area. $\frac{0.4}{9.97} \approx 0.04$
- **The M-type error or exaggeration** is the mean of the absolute observed effect of the rejected/significant cases relative to the true effect. In Figure 2 this is the mean of the red and the green points divided by the true effect. In the example this is approximately 1.70.

#### Connection between power and S-type and M-type errors

For two given samples with size $n$ and significance level $\alpha$ the power is a function of the *relative* effect size ([Cohen's d](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size#Cohen%27s_d)) as demonstrated in the question: [Power Analysis and the non central t distribution: what is the non-centrality parameter?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/491720/).

The type-S and type-M errors are similarly functions of the effect size (explained further in the last section). We can plot them side by side as monotonous functions of the effect size.

Since the three values, power, type-S and type-M errors, all have relationships with the effect size, this makes that they all have relationships among each other as well.

These relationships may not be easy to express with a simple mathematical expression, but one can use the graphs to find one from the other. For example, with a given power one estimates the effect size, then for this effect size one computes the s-type and M-type errors. (or for several different effect sizes one computes both power an error, then plot those two versus each other as horizontal and vertical axis in a scatterplot, see also Figure 4)

[image: example of relationship between 3 values for given n]

<sup>*Figure 3: example of relationships of three values (power, type-S error and type-M error) as function of the effect size for sample size $n=5$.*</sup>

---

#### Small difference to the `retrodesign` function

Note, in the article from Gelman and Carlin, they have a function `retrodesign` which they use to make the computations by using a shifted t-distribution. Here I used a non-central t-distribution which represents a t-test more accurately.

Also for computing the M-error with a t-test, the computation of the M-error should not simulate only the t-values but instead both the t-value and the effect size. The M-error is the mean absolute observed effect relative to the true effect, given that the observed effect is significant (we need to use the distribution in Figure 2 that is based on simulations like in Figure 1).

---

#### Generalization

This answer discusses the case of the two-sample t-test as in the reference of the question, but for other tests the computations might be different. There is no single fixed relationship between power and S-type and M-type errors.

The image 4 below demonstrates this for different values of $n$ and two types of statistical tests. (although arguably one may consider the cases to be very close)

[image: different type of tests]

<sup>*Figure 4: Example of different relationships between type S and type M errors with power, or different testing conditions.*</sup>

---

#### Replacing simulation with exact computations

Note that the histograms from Figure 2 can be expressed in terms of the distribution functions of the normal distribution and $\chi$ distribution. The histogram of the total of the points is normal distributed. The histogram of the significant points can be expressed as the density of the normal distribution multiplied with the cdf of a chi distribution. Potentially one might compute the m-type error based on this instead of using a simulation.

In the case of large $n$ the chi distribution approaches a singular distribution and the distribution of the significant/non-significant cases will become a truncated normal distribution.

#### Code for figures

With the code below one can make figures 3 and 4

```
library(retrodesign) ### for shifted t-distribution significance tests

### compute power and error rates for two sample t-test
retropower = function(d, n, alpha = 0.05, n.sim = 10^4) {
  nu = 2*n-2

  ### boundary for alpha level t-test
  tc = qt(1-alpha/2, df = nu)
  
  ### power 
  power = pt(-tc, df = nu, ncp=d/sqrt(2/n)) + 
        1-pt( tc, df = nu, ncp=d/sqrt(2/n))

  ### s-error rate
  type_s = pt(-tc, df = nu, ncp=d/sqrt(2/n))/power

  ### simulate experiments
  x0 = rnorm(n.sim,0)
  s = sqrt(rchisq(n.sim,nu)/nu) 
  
  ### m-error
  type_m = sapply(d, FUN = function(di) {
    x = abs(x0+di*sqrt(n/2))
    significant = x/s>tc
    return(mean(x[significant == 1]/sqrt(n/2))/di)  
  })
  return(list(power = power, type_s = type_s, type_m = type_m))
}


### some settings
set.seed(1)
d = seq(0,3,0.05)

####
### creating plots for image 4
####

layout(matrix(1:2,1, byrow = TRUE))
par(mgp =c(2,1,0), mar = c(4,4,3,1))

plot(2,2, log = "xy", type = "l", xlim = c(0.05,1), ylim = c(0.0001,1),
     xlab = "power", ylab = "type-s error")
m = c(5,20,100)
i = 0
for (mi in m) {
   i = i+1
   r = retropower(d/sqrt(mi/5),mi)
   q = retrodesign(A = as.list(d/sqrt(mi/5)), s = sqrt(2/mi), df = 2*mi - 2)
   
   lines(r$power,r$type_s, col = i)
   lines(q$power,q$type_s, col = i, lty = 2)
}

plot(2,2, log = "xy", type = "l", xlim = c(0.05,1), ylim = c(1,20),
     xlab = "power", ylab = "type-m error")

m = c(5,20,100)
i = 0
for (mi in m) {
  i = i+1
  r = retropower(d/sqrt(mi/5),mi)
  q = retrodesign(A = as.list(d/sqrt(mi/5)), s = sqrt(2/mi), df = 2*mi - 2)
  
  lines(r$power,r$type_m, col = i)
  lines(q$power,q$type_m, col = i, lty = 2)
  
}

title(main="type S/M errors versus power for different type of tests", outer=TRUE, line=-1, cex = 1)
legend(0.08,18, c("n=5","n=20","n=100"), col = c(1,2,3), lty = 1, cex = 0.7, title = "non-central\n t-distribution", box.lwd = 0)
legend(0.3,18, c("n=5","n=20","n=100"), col = c(1,2,3), lty = 2, cex = 0.7, title = "shifted\n t-distribution", box.lwd = 0)

####
## creating plots for image 3
###


d = seq(0,5,0.025)
r = retropower(d,5)

layout(matrix(1:3,3))
par(mgp =c(2,1,0), mar = c(4,4,2,1))

plot(d,r$power, type ="l", xlab = "effect size in terms of sigma", ylab = "power", main = "power for two sample test with n = 5" , ylim = c(0,1))
plot(d,r$type_s, type ="l", xlab = "effect size in terms of sigma", ylab = "error rate", main = "S-type error for two sample test with n = 5" , ylim = c(0,0.5))
plot(d,r$type_m, type ="l", xlab = "effect size in terms of sigma", ylab = "magnification", main = "M-type error for two sample test with n = 5" , ylim = c(0,30))
```

Comment: It might be worth adding that the exaggeration of effect size seen among 'significant' results comes from both sample means being larger than the population mean _and_ the standard deviation from the sample being lower than that of the population. I've got a nice illustration here:https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/164_2019_286/figures/6

Comment: @MichaelLew I have added an illustration now.

Comment: @MichaelLew That is a really good point that has been missed in other discussions of type S and M errors.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Thanks for a really helpful answer. Please make it more helpful by better labeling your last two figures. I don't entirely understand the Y axis (which you should clarify has nothing to do with Y in your equation) and don't understand at all where the diagonal lines come from.  It would also help to label the two panel as showing simulations from the null hypothesis the alternative.

Comment: @HarveyMotulsky I have made an update. Let me know if more can be changed.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus. Thanks. I think it can be more clear by making three points that are obvious to you but took me a few minutes to get:
-The t test computes t = (difference between means)/(SE of the difference)
- The horizontal axis on your two middle graphs (can't say X because you gave it a different meaning) are the differences
-The vertical axis is (or is proportional to) the SE of the differences
-The diagonal lines show all the points where the ratio is exactly the value of t that corresponds to 0.05.  Points towards the middle are p>0.05, the points nearer the extremes are p<0.05

Comment: @HarveyMotulsky those are good points (Especially that second point... I realise only now that I have always used x-and y-axis as synonym for horizontal and vertical axis, while that is not so clear language at all). I will incorporate the three points, but I will take some time to rewrite the entire question to make it more consistent.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus. Using x-and y-axis as synonyms for the horizontal and vertical axes is totally standard. But you first defined x and y to be the two groups being compared in the t-test.  Can't be both in one example

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus "There is no single fixed relationship between power and S-type and M-type errors." Do you mean that for a t test, the relationship is not fixed because it varies with sample size? Or that the relationship may be different for other kinds of test?

Comment: @HarveyMotulsky in my mind I had both. Because the relationship is different for different sample sizes in the t-test, the relationship will probably also be different for different kinds of tests. But, possibly a large range is asymptotically equivalent to normal distributed errors and also the differences might be small so a single curve based on a z-test might be a good rule of thumb. Maybe a Chebyshev's type of inequality could be formulated for upper and lower bounds of the relationship between the error rates and power?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus : You define the M-error by averaging the absolute values of all selected effects and divide by the true (simulated) population effect. But why include effects that go in the wrong direction? If the sign is wrong, who cares about the magnitude? Wouldn't it make more sense to only average the effects going in the right direction? I can't imagine it will make much difference, but it seems a more appropriate definitiion.

Comment: @HarveyMotulsky On could argue that it makes sense for simplicity of the concepts/definitions. You can describe a value by the sign and by the magnitude. Indeed, if you describe errors of the sign and errors the magnitude, then they will have some overlap. However the alternative for 'error of the sign' and 'error of the magnitude' would be 'error of the sign' and 'error of the magnitude conditional on the sign being true'...

Comment: ... the two errors are anyways more relevant as a heuristic tool to understand the wider range of error that may occur in hypothesis testing, especially when power is low. Setting up rules similar to the typical guidelines for minimal significance levels and power levels are a bit arbitrary and one may sacrifice the logic of not having overlap for simplicity.

Answer (score 4):

*To avoid notational difficulties, I will use notation to Gelman and Carlin, with the effect size represented as $\theta$ and upper-case $D$, $D^\text{rep}$, etc., used to represent the data as a random variable.*

We will consider a test with null hypothesis $H_0: \theta = 0$ with a test statistic $D$ which is an estimator for the true effect size.  We assume that the test is constructed with an evidentiary ordering that is more in favour of the alternative hypothesis for larger (absolute) magnitude of $D$, so the null hypothesis is rejected if the absolute magnitude of $D$ falls too far from zero.  Given a significance level $\alpha$ we let $d_\text{crit}$ denote the (positive) critical point of the test so that the the null is rejected if $|D| > d_\text{crit}$.  (Note that all of our analysis will implicitly depend on $\alpha$.)

In Gelman and Carlin there are some further simplifying assumptions made about the test that lead to a particular form for the sampling density for the test statistic.  Here we will proceed in generality by giving formulae that apply for any distribution of the test statistic.  To facilitate analysis of the quantities of interest, we define the intermediate quantities:

$$H_-(\theta) \equiv \mathbb{P}_\theta(D^\text{rep} < -d_\text{crit} )
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad 
H_+(\theta) \equiv \mathbb{P}_\theta(D^\text{rep} > d_\text{crit} ).$$

The quantities of interest can then be written as:

$$\begin{align}
\text{Power} (\theta)
&\equiv \mathbb{P}_\theta(p(D^\text{rep}) < \alpha) \\[18pt]
&= \mathbb{P}_\theta(|D^\text{rep}| > d_\text{crit}) \\[18pt]
&= \mathbb{P}_\theta(D^\text{rep} < -d_\text{crit} ) + \mathbb{P}_\theta(D^\text{rep} > d_\text{crit} ) \\[18pt]
&= H_-(\theta) + H_+(\theta). \\[24pt]
\text{Type-S Error Rate} (\theta)
&\equiv \mathbb{P}_\theta(D^\text{rep} < 0 |p(D^\text{rep}) < \alpha) \\[18pt]
&= \mathbb{P}_\theta(D^\text{rep} < 0 | |D^\text{rep}| > d_\text{crit} ) \\[10pt]
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}_\theta(D^\text{rep} < 0, |D^\text{rep}| > d_\text{crit} )}{\mathbb{P}_\theta(D^\text{rep} < 0, |D^\text{rep}| > d_\text{crit} ) + \mathbb{P}_\theta(D^\text{rep} \geqslant 0, |D^\text{rep}| > d_\text{crit} )} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}_\theta(D^\text{rep} < -d_\text{crit} )}{\mathbb{P}_\theta(D^\text{rep} < -d_\text{crit} ) + \mathbb{P}_\theta(D^\text{rep} > d_\text{crit} )} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{H_{-\text{sgn}(\theta)}(\theta)}{H_-(\theta) + H_+(\theta)}. \\[16pt]
\text{Exaggeration Ratio} (\theta)
&\equiv \frac{1}{\theta} \cdot \mathbb{E}_\theta(|D^\text{rep}| |p(D^\text{rep}) < \alpha) \\[10pt]
&= \frac{1}{\theta} \cdot \mathbb{E}_\theta(|D^\text{rep}| ||D^\text{rep}| > d_\text{crit}) \\[10pt]
&= \frac{1}{\theta} \Bigg[ \mathbb{E}_\theta(D^\text{rep}| D^\text{rep} > d_\text{crit}) \cdot H_+(\theta) - \mathbb{E}_\theta(D^\text{rep}| D^\text{rep} < -d_\text{crit}) \cdot H_-(\theta) \Bigg]. \\[10pt]
\end{align}$$

(Note that even though we are proceeding here for the case where $\theta>0$, to make things easier I have given the more general formula for the Type-S error in the last step.)

Comment: I corrected what I think was a small typo. Please roll back the edit if this was mistaken.