# Properties of a distribution obtained by filtering normal distributed variables by the result of a t-test

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, t-test

#### Two sample t-test

Consider the following t-test

Let $x_1, \dots, x_n \sim N(\mu_1,\sigma^2)$ and $y_1, \dots, y_n \sim N(\mu_2,\sigma^2)$ be independent samples. Let's define

- The raw effect

  $\begin{align}\theta = \mu_2-\mu_1\end{align}$
- The estimate of the raw effect

  $\begin{align}\hat{\theta} = \bar{Y} - \bar{X} \sim N \left(\theta,\frac{2}{n} \sigma^2 \right)\end{align}$
- The standard error of the raw effect

  $\begin{array}{RCL}\text{se}(\hat\theta) &=& \sqrt\frac{2}{n} \hat\sigma \\&= &\sqrt\frac{2}{n}  \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar{X})^2 + \sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\bar{Y})^2}{2n -2}} \\&\sim &\sigma\sqrt{\frac{2}{n}} \sqrt{\frac{1}{2n-2}} \chi_{2n-2}\end{array}$

where $a\chi_{2n-2}$ means a scaled chi distribution (also known as a case of the gamma distribution).

The t-statistic is defined as

$$t = \frac{\hat\theta}{\text{se}(\hat\theta)} \sim t_{2n-2,\theta\sqrt{n/2}}$$

#### Distribution of the effect conditional on significance

A null hypothesis test will consider estimates $\hat\theta$ significant or not significant according to the value of the t-statistic and some cutoff value $t_c$

$$\begin{array}{rl}
\text{significant: }&|t| \geq t_c\\
\text{non-significant: }&|t| < t_c
\end{array}$$

we consider the distribution of the effect size conditional on the null hypothesis test to be significant

$$f(\hat{\theta} \text{ given } |t| \geq t_c)$$
where additional parameters are the the significance level $\alpha$, sample size $n$ and true effect size $d$.

A simulation shows that this distribution looks as follows for $\alpha = 0.05$, $n = 5$ and $d = 0.5$.

[image: example simulation]

Aside from making a histogram we can also compute the distribution based on the PDF of the normal distribution $\phi(x)$ and CDF of the chi-squared distribution $F_{\chi^2_\nu}(x)$

$$f(\hat\theta;d,n,t_c)  \propto \phi\left(\frac{\hat\theta-d}{\sqrt{2/n}}\right)F_{\chi^2_\nu}\left(\frac{(n-1) n\hat\theta^2}{t_c^2}\right)$$

---

#### Question

Can we compute or estimate (in a way that is more efficient than Monte Carlo sampling or integration) the following two properties?

The CDF

$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^0 f(\hat{\theta}) d\hat\theta\end{align}$

and the mean absolute value

$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\hat\theta| f(\hat{\theta}) d\hat\theta\end{align}$

The motivation is that these relate to the type S and type M errors, as described in the questions:

- [The probability of making a Type S error, and the average amount of magnification (type M error) as a function of power](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/616912)
- [Power paradox: overestimated effect size in low-powered study, but the estimator is unbiased](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/595053)
- [Understanding Gelman & Carlin "Beyond Power Calculations: ..." (2014)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/243412)

---

R-code for image

```
### settings
set.seed(1)
d = 0.2
n = 5
nu = 2*n-2
alpha = 0.05
n.sim = 10^5


### boundary for alpha level t-test
tc = qt(1-alpha/2, df = nu)


#### simulations of t-test

effect = rep(NA,n.sim)
significant= rep(NA,n.sim)

for (i in 1:n.sim) {
   X = rnorm(n)
   Y = rnorm(n,d)
   significant[i] = t.test(X,Y)$p.value < alpha
   effect[i] = mean(Y)-mean(X)
}


### significance tests
#effect = rnorm(n.sim,d,sqrt(2/n))
#s = sqrt(rchisq(n.sim,nu)/nu)*sqrt(2/n)
#significant = abs(effect/s)>tc

### plot histogram
hist(effect[significant], breaks = seq(-3.5,3.5,0.1), freq = 0)

### add computation of density curve
power = pt(-tc,nu,d/sqrt(2/n)) +
1-pt(tc,nu,d/sqrt(2/n))
power
xs = seq(-4,4,0.01)
#lines(xs,dnorm(xs,d, sqrt(2/n))/power)

pfilter = (xs/tc)^2*(nu*n/2)
lines(xs,dnorm(xs,d, sqrt(2/n))*pchisq(pfilter,nu)/power)
```

Comment: +1 I think a [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/595053/247274) of mine from last year is related to this.